# Desktop is not showing in Powershell directory

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-code

I am new to using Powershell and programming. I am trying to change the directory of a file to run through Visual Studio. Through file share I am typing cd .\desktop\woodcutter\ (woodcutter is the name of the file). There is an error that states,

PS C:\Users\music>
PS C:\Users\music> cd .\Desktop\woodcutter
cd : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\music\Desktop\woodcutter' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1

- cd .\Desktop\woodcutter\
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\music\Desktop\woodcutter\:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFound
  Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
  ```

and on VS Code is saying, Can't find Node.js binary "node": path does not exist. Make sure Node.js is installed and in your PATH, or set the "runtimeExecutable" in your launch.json.

How would I be able to run the file through VS Code and how do I find the Directory for it to work?

Comment: You need to pass a fully qualified name as a path, and that includes the file extension. You also must make sure your executable application path is in your System Path or PS path profile.

Comment: ```[System.Enum]::GetNames([System.Environment+SpecialFolder])|ForEach-Object{@{$_=[Environment]::GetFolderPath($_)}}``` gives a list of commonly known (and present by default) folders in Windows (so called *special* or *shell* folders.)